# Problem of proving a factorial representation

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers such that $k\le n!$ . Then prove that positive integers $d(i)$ exist such that $0\le d(i)\le  n-i$, $k = 1 + d(1)(n-1)! + d(2)(n-2)! + \ldots + d(n-1) 1!$. Also prove their uniqueness.

My book says that *"these $d(i)$s have some combinatoric significance, but we shall not go into it"*. I would like you explain me the combinatoric significance as well.

Comment: With a half-dozen questions under your belt, surely it is time for you to master MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Thanks I will be using it from now on.

Comment: Right now $d$ isn't unique. Did you mean to specify that $d(i)$ must be integer?

Comment: Yes   it is a integer. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(i)$ form the [factoradic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) digits of $k - 1$. [As the wiki explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations), the combinatorial significance is a mapping between numbers written in factoradic and permutations of $n$ elements in lexicographic order.

Comment: You didn't state the proof.